# Add new subform records based on number in main form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to enter a numeric value into a mainfrom text box and create that many new records onto the subform. So a value of 4 in the mainform textbox will create 4 new subform records

I'm looking for a jumping off point example of what the basic code might look like.

Here is what I've got so far. But, it is not creating the new records. I get the you are about to append 0 row(s) x number of times

```
Private Sub Command153_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim sqlNewSamples As String
    Dim intNumberOfSamples As Integer
    Dim intNOSCounter As Integer

    intNOSCounter = 0
    intNumberOfSamples = Me.NumberOfSamples

    sqlNewSamples = "INSERT INTO tbl_Samples ( GroupID ) " & _
                    "SELECT tbl_Samples.GroupID " & _
                    "FROM tbl_Samples " & _
                    "WHERE (((tbl_Samples.GroupID)=[Forms]![frm_Login]![SampleGroupID]));"

    Do Until intNOSCounter = intNumberOfSamples
        DoCmd.RunSQL sqlNewSamples
        intNOSCounter = intNOSCounter + 1
    Loop   
End Sub
```

---

```
sqlNewSamples = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Samples] ( GroupID ) " & _
                "SELECT [tbl_Samples].GroupID " & _
                "FROM [tbl_Samples] " & _
                "WHERE ((([tbl_Samples].GroupID)=[Forms]![frm_Login]![SampleGroupID]));"
```

---

Private Sub Command153_Click()

```
Dim intNumberOfSamples As Integer
Dim intNOSCounter As Integer

  intNumberOfSamples = Me.NumberOfSamples

  For i = 1 To intNumberOfSamples
   rst.AddNew
   rst!GroupID = Me!SampleGroupID
   rst!SubID = i    '\\if you need distinct records
   rst.Update
Next i

Do Until intNOSCounter = intNumberOfSamples

   intNOSCounter = intNOSCounter + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

---

```
'Final Working Code
Private Sub Command154_Click()

Dim intNumberOfSamples As Integer
Dim intNOSCounter As Integer
Dim NrOfSamples As Integer
Dim strSampleNumber As String

    intNOSCounter = 0
    intNumberOfSamples = Me.NumberOfSamples

Do Until intNOSCounter = intNumberOfSamples

Forms![frm_Login]![Samples].SetFocus
Forms![frm_Login]![Samples].Form.GroupSampleNumber.SetFocus

    intNOSCounter = intNOSCounter + 1
Forms![frm_Login]![Samples].Form.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

    Loop

Me.SetFocus
Me.NumberOfSamples.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to refresh/requery the subform when finished... Just before 'End Sub'.

Comment: Oh yeah @WayneG.Dunn you're right . But I also think there is an issue  with my sql statement

Comment: I created a query based on what you have (changed table & field names), and after putting [] around my tablename, it ran just file. My field was text, but that's ok as long as the query references a proper control name. Add a msgbox in your loop to display the value in SampleGroupID.

Comment: I tried adding the [] around the table names (posted above) but I am still getting 0 rows added

Comment: Add two debug.print statements after the SQL is built: (1) Debug.Print sqlNewSamples   and (2) Debug.Print ">" & [Forms]![frm_Login]![SampleGroupID] & "<"      Run the sql in a query window. If it still fails, then investigate the value.

Comment: First, your query will only work if there is an existing GroupID already in the tbl_Samples table.  If GroupID does not exist in the table already, then the SELECT statement will return zero rows, so there will be nothing to be inserted.  *** If GroupID is in the table, it looks to me like it will cascade, adding more and more records each time the query is executed, because the query would return each previously added row.  Why not just insert the value directly, like `INSERT INTO tbl_Samples ( GroupID ) SELECT ([Forms]![frm_Login]![SampleGroupID]) As NewGroupID`?

Comment: WayneG.Dunn gives a good hint at debugging, but in debugging INSERT... SELECT statements, it is best to run the SELECT statement separately and see what it returns.  After running `Debug.Print sqlNewSamples`, copy the SELECT SQL into a query window and look-see.  Also, analyze each part of the SQL and figure out what it is doing--"execute" the query in your mind and try to predict what the outcome would be rather than just tweaking the code and re-running until it works.

Comment: Shouldn't the sqlNewSamples be inside your DO loop?  Or you're just entering the same data x amount of times.  Each iteration should also INSERT a unique (intNOSCounter?) value in one of your destination fields.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a recordset, and update your subform table?  Prior to doing this, delete any records in the subform table.

```
for i = 1 to intNumberOfSamples
   rst.addnew
   rst!GroupID = me!SampleGroupID
   rst!SubID = i    '\\if you need distinct records
   rst.update
next i
```

Comment: @C Perkins, that worked. I'd also loike to try @geeFlo 's idea of using a recordset. I opted the code above but it throws a "Run-time error '424' Object required at 'rst.AddNew'

Comment: As unorthodox as it seems, the final working code seems to work. By simply adding a new record and setting the focus to the GroupSampleNumber, this allowed to the OnGotFocus code to fire which not only populates the required fields but also creates the Unique code the user requires.